# How to not have errors for bad EOL escaping jQuery

Tags: jquery, warnings, sublimetext3, eol

Currently I do this:

```
$appendedItems.append('\
    <li class="user_profile_card" style="'+newline+'">\
        <div class="line-structure-top"></div>\
        <div class="top-colour-section-tier2"></div>\
        ...
    </li>');
```

But sublime returns bad escaping of EOL errors / warnings. I could just ignore it, but hate seeing the warnings.

How should this be done correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use string concatenation instead:

```
$appendedItems.append('<li class="user_profile_card" style="' + newline + '">' +
    '<div class="line-structure-top"></div>' +
    '<div class="top-colour-section-tier2"></div>' +
'</li>');
```